# How to detect if an object encapsulate another?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

Assuming I have an image with multiple objects:
[image]
I want to detect that there is a square (and a harder case of a hollow circle) inside a larger square.
My starting point was to use k-means but I don't know how to tell which mask is which, and the code can break quickly if there is enough noise in the background (non white background).

Comment: The image seems to be noisy enough, Can you assure that the colors of respective figures(circle, rect, etc.) would be consistent in each case ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't even guarantee each object will have the same shade of color (but I can experiment with K size until I find a one that can give a good segmentation)

Comment: if you give one of your images to a person and just tell her to segment the objects, without telling her more, would you expect her to segment it the right way? For example in your image it is even for a human ambiguous whether the red circle inside of the yellow-green circle on the yellow-green circle or whether the yellow-green circle has a hole and it is instead part of the red square in the background. In your example I would suggest contour extraction as a first step, but that probably won't work in your real-world scenario...

Comment: I support @Micka, you need to be consistent on some level, otherwise there won't be any basis for segmentation, You may start with kmeans clustering but you will find out shortly that it would group the dissimilar objects as a single cluster, since you have no pre information of the desired color, you would not be able to derive some meaningful information from the results.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately those are the parameters of the problem. I was thinking to iterate over different K values, for each value I will go over the masks and do a contour filling, then for each two masks I apply a logic AND operation and if the results has a high number of true values then I have two shapes one inside the other. I can stop the K iterations once this requirement is fulfilled.